# Teradata Driver for .NET Core

Tags: .net-core, teradata

Does anyone know of any options for connecting to a Teradata DB from .NET Core?

.NET Standard 2.0 doesn't support ODBC, and the current driver page from Teradata doesn't show a .NET Core provider.

https://downloads.teradata.com/download/connectivity/net-data-provider-for-teradata

This would be .NET Core running on a Debian docker image.

Comment: Hi, I'm also sailing in the same boat. Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Looks like they won't be supporting this until sometime in 2018. [link](https://community.teradata.com/t5/Connectivity/Teradata-Driver-for-NET-Core/td-p/74224)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a .NET Standard 2.0+ compatible NuGet package now that uses `System.Data.DataSet` instead of `System.Data.Odbc`:

> .NET Data Provider for Teradata 16.20.7 supports .NET Core 2.0 and higher. It is generally available now on Windows, Linux and macOS.

Reference: [Teradata.Client.Provider](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Teradata.Client.Provider/)